# Generating 10 random numbers without duplicate with fundamental techniques

Tags: java, arrays, loops

my intend is to use simplest java (array and loops) to generate random numbers without duplicate...but the output turns out to be 10 repeating numbers, and I cannot figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
int[] number = new int[10];
int count = 0;
int num;

while (count < number.length) {
    num = r.nextInt(21);
    boolean repeat = false;
    do {
        for (int i=0; i<number.length; i++) {
            if (num == number[i]) {
                repeat = true;
            } else if (num != number[i] && i == count) {
                number[count] = num;
                count++;
                repeat = true;
            }
        }
    } while (!repeat);
}

for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
    System.out.print(number[j] + " ");
}
```

Comment: What output does this produce?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a description of a problem. What do you expect it to do, what does it do instead?

Comment: My guess is that you should be setting `repeat` to `false` inside either the `if` block or the `else` block, but I haven't read the code too closely.

Comment: How about using true random functions? And generating real random numbers is a highly complex matter. What is the purpose of this? Do you have experience with number theory or theoretical informatics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `break` out of the `for` loop if either of the conditions are met.

```
    int[] number = new int[10];
    int count=0;
    int num;
    Random r = new Random();
    while(count<number.length){
        num = r.nextInt(21);
        boolean repeat=false;
        do{
            for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++){
                if(num==number[i]){
                    repeat=true;
                    break;
                }
                else if(i==count){
                    number[count]=num;
                    count++;
                    repeat=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(!repeat);

    }

    for(int j=0;j<number.length;j++){
        System.out.print(number[j]+" ");
    }
```

This will make YOUR code work but @gonzo proposed a better solution.

Answer (score 9):

How about you use a `Set` instead? If you also want to keep track of the order of insertion you can use a `LinkedHashSet`.

```
Random r = new Random();
Set<Integer> uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<>();
while (uniqueNumbers.size()<10){
    uniqueNumbers.add(r.nextInt(21));
}
for (Integer i : uniqueNumbers){
    System.out.print(i+" ");
}
```

A `Set` in java is like an `Array` or an `ArrayList` except it handles duplicates for you. It will only add the `Integer` to the set if it doesn't already exist in the set. The class `Set` has similar methods to the `Array` that you can utilize. For example `Set.size()` is equivalent to the `Array.length` and `Set.add(Integer)` is semi-equivalent to `Array[index] = value`. Sets do not keep track of insertion order so they do not have an index. It is a very powerful tool in Java once you learn about it. ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this helps, I do believe that the code needs a detailed explanation on the classes / concepts used. The OP question is early knowledge, and I believe he/she does not grasp it yet.

Comment: @Bonatti will do. I learned Sets same time as Arrays so just assumed OP knew what a set was. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: @crystal no problem. :) Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will break the while loop under the condition: `num == number[i]`.

This means that if the pseudo-generated number is equal to that positions value (the default `int` in java is 0), then the code will end execution.

On the second conditional, the expression `num != number[i]` is always true (otherwise the code would have entered the previous `if`), but, on the first run, when `i == count` (or `i=0`, and `count=0`) the `repeat=true` breaks the loop, and nothing else would happen, rendering the output something such as

```
0 0 0 0 0 0...
```

Comment: so i should modify the second conditional? can you give further explanation on that?

Comment: I would suggest an analisys on the problem. You want to have an array with different values, most answers here will show you how, I will not =] I will instead show how to approach the problem. First start by having a array with an initial value (`int numbers = new int[10]` will have 10 zero value integers). Then, start populating that array `count` will be the position, starting at 0. Randomize a value in a variable (`num = r.nextInt(21)`), and check if that value is present from the initial position until the count position...if you reached up to count, then you can insert that value...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    int[] number = new int[10];
    java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();

    for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++){
        boolean repeat=false;

        do{
            repeat=false;

            int num = r.nextInt(21);
            for(int j=0; j<number.length; j++){
                if(number[j]==num){
                    repeat=true;
                }
            }

            if(!repeat) number[i]=num;

        }while(repeat);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < number.length; k++) {
        System.out.print(number[k] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

[Test it here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRU1wOXJmOFo0NFk).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is much easier to solve.  You could use a List to check if the number has been generated or not (uniqueness).  Here is a working block of code.

```
    int count=0;
    int num;
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    while (count<10) {        
        num = r.nextInt(21);  
        if(!numbers.contains(num) ) {
            numbers.add(num);
            count++;
        }
    }

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        System.out.print(numbers.get(j)+" ");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the most simple approach, putting 10 random - potentially duplicated - numbers into an array:

```
public class NonUniqueRandoms
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] number = new int[10];
        int count = 0;

        while (count < number.length) {
            // Use ThreadLocalRandom so this is a contained compilable unit
            number[count++] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(21);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(number[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

So that gets you most of the way there, the only thing you know have to do is pick a number and check your array:

```
public class UniqueRandoms
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] number = new int[10];
        int count = 0;

        while (count < number.length) {
            // Use ThreadLocalRandom so this is a contained compilable unit
            int candidate = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(21);

            // Is candidate in our array already?
            boolean exists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (number[i] == candidate) {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // We didn't find it, so we're good to add it to the array
            if (!exists) {
                number[count++] = candidate;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(number[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your inner 'for' loop. Once the program finds a unique integer, it adds the integer to the array and then increments the count. On the next loop iteration, the new integer will be added again because (num != number[i] && i == count), eventually filling up the array with the same integer. The for loop needs to exit after adding the unique integer the first time.

But if we look at the construction more deeply, we see that the inner for loop is entirely unnecessary.

See the code below.

```
   import java.util.*;

   public class RandomDemo {
      public static void main( String args[] ){
        // create random object
        Random r = new Random();

        int[] number = new int[10];
        int count = 0;
        int num;

        while (count < number.length) {
               num = r.nextInt(21);
               boolean repeat = false;
               int i=0;

               do {
                  if (num == number[i]) {
                     repeat = true;
                  } else if (num != number[i] && i == count) {
                     number[count] = num;
                     count++;
                     repeat = true;
                  }

                  i++;

               } while (!repeat && i < number.length);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
               System.out.print(number[j] + " ");
        }
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach.

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class uniquerandom {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int qask[]=new int[10];
    int it,i,t=0,in,flag;


        for(it=0;;it++)
        {
            i=rnd.nextInt(11);
            flag=0; 
            for(in=0;in<qask.length;in++)
            {
                if(i==qask[in])
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag!=1)
            {
                qask[t++]=i;
            }
            if(t==10)
                break;          
        }

        for(it=0;it<qask.length;it++)
            System.out.println(qask[it]);

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String pickStringElement(ArrayList list, int... howMany) {
    int counter = howMany.length > 0 ? howMany[0] : 1;
    String returnString = "";
    ArrayList previousVal = new ArrayList()
    for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random()
        for(int j=1; j <=list.size(); j++){
            int newRand = rand.nextInt(list.size())
            if (!previousVal.contains(newRand)){
                previousVal.add(newRand)
                returnString = returnString + (i>1 ? ", " + list.get(newRand) :list.get(newRand))
                break
            }
        }
     }
    return returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create simple method and call it where you require**-

```
private List<Integer> q_list = new ArrayList<>(); //declare list integer type

private void checkList(int size)
    {
        position = getRandom(list.size()); //generating random value less than size
        if(q_list.contains(position)) { // check if list contains position
            checkList(size); /// if it contains call  checkList method again
        }
        else
        {
            q_list.add(position); // else add the position in the list 
         
            playAnimation(tv_questions, 0, list.get(position).getQuestion()); // task you want to perform after getting value
        }

    }
```

for getting random value this method is being called-

```
 public static int getRandom(int max){
        return (int) (Math.random()*max);
    }
```